# MySQL INNER JOIN returns zero results if all values are not found

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query that works great when all of the INNER JOIN criteria is met.  Unfortunately, this query returns zero results when for example `INNER JOIN TableSample6 ON TableSample1.Field4 = TableSample6.Field6` is not found.

Can I restructure this query to return results even if some of the INNER JOIN values do not have a match in some cases?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TableSample1.Field4, 
    TableSample.Field2,
    TableSample2.Field2,
    TableSample3.Field3,
    TableSample4.Field4,
    TableSample5.Field1,
    TableSample.Field3,
    TableSample6.Field1,
    TableSample6.Field2,
    TableSample7.Field7,
    TableSample3.Field4,
    TableSample4.Field2,
    TableSample5.Field4
FROM TableSample1 
        INNER JOIN TableSample2 ON TableSample1.Field2 = TableSample2.Field4
        INNER JOIN TableSample ON TableSample1.Field6 = TableSample.Field4
        INNER JOIN TableSample3 ON TableSample1.Field3 = TableSample3.Field2        
        INNER JOIN TableSample4 ON TableSample1.Field7 = TableSample4.Field3
        INNER JOIN TableSample5 ON TableSample1.Field8 = TableSample5.Field2        
        INNER JOIN TableSample6 ON TableSample1.Field4 = TableSample6.Field6
WHERE (((TableSample1.Field4)="xxxxxx" AND (TableSample.Field2)="xxxxxx"))
    ORDER BY TableSample1.Field2;
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is essense is a *filter*.  So use some form of `OUTER JOIN` and control `IS NULL` wherever neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.Field4, 
    t.Field2,
    t2.Field2,
    t3.Field3,
    t4.Field4,
    t5.Field1,
    t.Field3,
    t6.Field1,
    t6.Field2,
    t7.Field7,     -- PROBLEM: you never join to TableSample7
    t3.Field4,
    t4.Field2,
    t5.Field4
FROM TableSample1 t1
LEFT JOIN TableSample2 t2
    ON t1.Field2 = t2.Field4
LEFT JOIN TableSample t
    ON t1.Field6 = t.Field4
LEFT JOIN TableSample3 t3
    ON t1.Field3 = t3.Field2        
LEFT JOIN TableSample4 t4
    ON t1.Field7 = t4.Field3
LEFT JOIN TableSample5 t5
    ON t1.Field8 = t5.Field2        
LEFT JOIN TableSample6 t6
    ON t1.Field4 = t6.Field6
WHERE t1.Field4 = "xxxxxx" AND
      t.Field2 = "xxxxxx"
ORDER BY t1.Field2;
```

You could also use `COALESCE()` to handle records which do not match to all of the tables.  For example, if `TableSample2.Field2` were varchar, you could use `COALESCE(t2.Field2, 'NA')` to show `NA` instead of `NULL`.